# Meaning of first cohomology of normal bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

The dimension of the zeroth cohomology $H^0(C,N_{C/X})$ of the normal bundle of a curve $C$ in an ambient space $X$ counts the number of possible deformations of $C$ in $X$.

Is there any similar intuitive/geometric meaning for $H^1(C,N_{C/X})$?

Comment: See theorem $6.2$ in Hartshorne's ''Deformation Theory''. Basically, if $Y_0\subseteq X_0$ is a closed subscheme and $A$ is a local Artin ring then there is a class in $H^1$ associated to this data which is zero iff there is a deformation $Y\subseteq X_0\times_kA$ of $Y_0$ over $A$. In particular, if $H^1(\mathcal{N}_{Y_0/X_0})=0$ then deformations over all local Artin rings exist. If there are no obstructions, then there are $H^0$ many deformations. (I've been sloppy with not saying what exactly I'm taking cohomology of- see Hartshorne for it done properly).